# How to add multiple spaces to end of string?

Tags: php

I'm trying to add spaces to end of words so it look aligned to the next word. I've tried `str_pad` and `str_replace` but it didn't work.

```php
    $str = array("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six");

    ///with str_pad
    foreach ($str as $value) {
        if (strlen($value) <= 5) {
            $pad_str = str_pad($value, 6, " ", STR_PAD_RIGHT);
            $result = $pad_str.'bar';
            echo $result.'<br>';
        }
    }
    ///with str_replace
    foreach ($str as $value) {
        if (strlen($value) <= 5) {
            $rep_str = str_repeat(" ", max(0, 6 - strlen($value)));
            $result = $value.$rep_str.'bar';
            echo $result.'<br>';
        }
    }
```

I want something like this:

```
//output I want            //output returned
one   bar                  one bar
two   bar                  two bar
three bar                  three bar
four  bar                  four bar
five  bar                  five bar
six   bar                  six bar
```

How can I achieve this. I've tried for hours but didn't get the right answerer. So Please help.

Comment: Both your approaches works, you would realize it if you would wrap it with `<pre></pre>` tag, just HTML always display multiple spaces as one in the browser. You can also see it works running script as CLI in terminal and using `PHP_EOL` instead of `'<br>'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **PHP_EOL** and add `<pre></pre>` tags to display your result as you want:

```
<?php

 $str = array("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six");

echo '<pre>';    

    ///with str_pad
    foreach ($str as $value) {
        if (strlen($value) <= 5) {
            $pad_str = str_pad($value, 6, " ", STR_PAD_RIGHT);
            $result = $pad_str.'bar';
            echo $result.PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

echo '</pre>';
```

[Online](https://3v4l.org/8fJbk)

Comment: I'm running the script on localhost and it is showing the whole output in one line instead of newlines.

Comment: @Mujtaba  Wrap the whole thing with `<pre>` tag, otherwise browser display it as common free text. See my comment to the question, that's the same issue.

Comment: @Mujtaba check edited answer, Mathieu hope you don't mind I edited your post

Comment: No worries, I was going to do it @biesior

Answer (score 0):

just find the max length of value in array and repeat the white space accordingly.

Like,

```
$str = array("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six");
$max_len = max(array_map('strlen', $str)); // max length of value in array

echo "<pre>";

foreach ($str as $value) {
     $add_space = $max_len - strlen($value); 
     echo $value.str_repeat('&nbsp;', $add_space + 1)."bar"; echo "<br>";
}

echo "</pre>";
```